# How to locate relevant webElement by java selenium

Tags: java, xml, selenium, intellij-idea

Please see below attached [image]the relevant XML code and my java code to locate the element:

Java code:

```
    //Set date range
    WebElement parentStartdate = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=typein_[Parameters].[Parameter 3]]"));
    WebElement child=parentStartdate.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1/1/2019']"));
```

I get the follow error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id=typein_[Parameters].[Parameter 3]] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[@id=typein_[Parameters].[Parameter 3]]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

The whole xml structure:
[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: @DimaBokov DebanjanB said you should not post screenshots when you can copy and paste code and/or errors.

Comment: Did you tried something like : `By.xpath("//[@id='typein_[Parameters].[Parameter 3]']")`

Comment: @QubesX, yes, i've tried and it is not work also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one QueryBox on the webpage then you can select the element by using the following xpath for your case:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='QueryBox']"));`

Comment: Not works:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='QueryBox']"}

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of whole div structure of the element, would be helpful to get the xpath

Comment: added at the question

Comment: Can you please check that the element you are referring to is located under an iframe. To check that, please inspect the element by firepath and check corresponding to the xpath field that its written "Top Window" or "iframe" ?

Comment: it's an iframe:
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" title="data visualization" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: visible;" src="https://reports.internal.outbrain.com/views/_AmplifyAccountsDashboard/FiltersSelection?:embed=y&amp;:showVizHome=n&amp;:toolbar=top&amp;%3AopenAuthoringInTopWindow=true&amp;%3AbrowserBackButtonUndo=true&amp;%3AcommentingEnabled=true&amp;%3AreloadOnCustomViewSave=true&amp;%3AshowAppBanner=false&amp;%3AisVizPortal=true&amp/iframe>

Comment: Yup, so you need to first switch to the iframe and then operate on the element. To switch to the iframe, please use: 

`WebElement iFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));`
and then

`driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);` 
and then try to find the webelement using its xpath. It should work. 
To go back to the default frame, you can use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: Tnx, what is frame(iFrame):
iFrame - it's couldn't resolve the symbol...

Comment: Please use WebElement line code which i have used to declare the iFrame and find its path. And then use the switchTo line code

Comment: Great, happy to help !!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, that is not a valid Xpath expression. Select the first element by

```
WebElement parentStartdate = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='TypeInQuerySpan']/input"));
```

Comment: Sorry, not works:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='TypeInQuerySpan']/input"}

Comment: Can you locate the element manually? Go to DevTools and in the console type `$x("//span[@class='TypeInQuerySpan']/input")` and see if you can see the element and report here.

Comment: That's what i get:
$x("//span[@class='TypeInQuerySpan']/input")
(2) [input.QueryBox, input.QueryBox]

Comment: That means the xpath I gave you isn't unique. There are two elements that are located by it. What do you get when you expand those input.QueryBox elements?

Comment: The result:
$x("//span[@class='TypeInQuerySpan']/input")
(2) [input.QueryBox, input.QueryBox]
0: input.QueryBox
1: input.QueryBox
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: First switch to iframe, then try to select the element again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'TypeInDiv')]/span[@class="TypeInQuerySpan"]/input[@type='text'][@class='QueryBox'][@value='1/1/2019']
```

the 3 identifiers on input are not mandatory, you can choose 1 or 2 or leave all 3, you decide.